# Putting Title into Navigation Back bar in Xamrin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi I seem to be having issues getting my title to appear in the back bar part of the navigation area.

This is my code in my xaml:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="Project.Settings">
 <NavigationPage.TitleView>
     <Label Text="Settings" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
 </NavigationPage.TitleView>
<ContentPage.Content>
   
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This is my code in my xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project
{
    public partial class Settings : ContentPage
    {
        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
            NavigationPage.GetTitleView(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my code is doing:
[image: Title below Navigationbar]

I want to do this:
[image: Title in Navbar]

Comment: Can you update your question with complete Xaml code

Comment: I checked the same code with yours. It works on my side. Please check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/fTFPvfh Could do you provide more details?

Comment: Navingation.Pushasync(new navigationpage(new yourpagename())); try to open page as a navigation page. Everything else from your code seems fine.

Comment: It's the same code with what i tested. I tested on iphone12 14.4. Please creatte a new project to check again.